# Не добавляются сообщения

Tags: ajax, php, post, javascript

Всегда так, создашь вопрос, и сразу сам нашел косячек :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

7 раз проверь - один раз напиши. Слоган некоторых программистов. Удачи)